# Reading an XML using JAXB dynamically

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to extract the various fields of an various XMLs dynamically using JAXB. An example of one is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Entities TotalResults="1">
    <Entity Type="test-set-folder">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>1760</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="ver-stamp">
                <Value>0</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="parent-id">
                <Value>109</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="last-modified">
                <Value>2017-02-24 15:50:36</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="hierarchical-path">
                <Value>AAAAAAABN</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="description">
                <Value /> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="view-order" /> 
            <Field Name="name">
                <Value>ABCDEF</Value> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="attachment">
                <Value /> 
            </Field>
            <Field Name="workflow">
                <Value /> 
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities /> 
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

I want to do this dynamically as the fields change for every XML. My basic aim is to capture each field as use it for my convenience. For example, `field.id` should return 1760, etc.

My `Entity.java` is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Entities")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    Map<QName, String> otherAttributes;

    String name;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    List<Object> otherElements;

}
```

The code for calling Entity.java is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("path\\to xml\\file");
        Entity entity  = (Entity) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        // Mapped XML Attribute
        System.out.println("entity.id");
        System.out.println("    " + entity.id);

        // Other XML Attributes
        System.out.println("entity.otherAttributes");
        for(Entry<QName, String> entry : entity.otherAttributes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("    " + entry);
        }

        // Mapped XML Element
        System.out.println("entity.name");
        System.out.println("    " + entity.name);

        // Other XML Elements
        System.out.println(entity.otherElements);
        for(Object object : entity.otherElements) {
            System.out.println("    " + object);
        }

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(entity, System.out);
    }

}
```

My confusion is that the XML is nested, i.e. the fourth layer of data is what I'm interested in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Entities TotalResults="1">
    <Entity Type="test-set-folder">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>1760</Value> 
            </Field>
            .
            .
            .
```

My code for the Entity class is probably wrong, but can someone help me with how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must look at the below example where xml structure can vary and still you are able to load content using jaxB

[XSD schema for xml file that can change for JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776746/xsd-schema-for-xml-file-that-can-change-for-jaxb)

Lets see if it works for you!

Comment: Adding this as a comment will be more appropriate

Comment: Can you explain how this answer is supposed to help me?
How am I supposed to generate xsds for over a lakh xmls retrieved?